# Html button containing an dynamic image - Sizing

Tags: html, image, css, button

I want to show an image embedded within a button. The image is a dynamic and I would prefer to show the image as the background as I want to change the image on hover and click.
The difficulty I am facing is that: I want the button to resize according to the size of the background  image. As the image is dynamic and I have no knowledge of its size prior.
Example:

```
 <button id="rock" style='background-image: url(http://th07.deviantart.net/fs70/150/i/2013/012/c/6/rock_01_png___by_alzstock-d5r84up.png)'>Test Rock</button>

http://jsfiddle.net/5z1L67fw/1/
```

Other option I have is to include an img child element on the button element. However, in such a scenario is it possible to change the image on hover and press?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using img as childrens.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/5mn0szq6/

Keep two img tags inside button. Show only one tag initially. When button is hovered, hide the visible img and show the hidden img. Same logic can be applied for click/press too.

**HTML**:

```
<button>
    <img class="a" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/600/200/sports/1/" />
    <img class="b" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/600/200/sports/2/" />
</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
button {
    width:600px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.b {
    display:none;
}
button:hover .b {
    display:block;
}
button:hover .a {
    display:none;
}
```

This is only for hover effect. You have to write javascript for click handler.

For variable width, just remove the dimension from the button. The button will adjust itself based on new image size.

Demo :http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/5mn0szq6/1/

Comment: @ViruZX Does it make any difference? You can remove the dimension from button and based on the new visible image, button will adjust itself.

Comment: @ViruZX : Here is the demo for you to see: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/5mn0szq6/1/

Answer (score 1):

If you use child images you may not be able to show the text over the image.
So you can change the background image dynamically on mouse over(hover).

Please see this demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/cyB7B/722/

```
<button type="image" 
style="background-image: url('http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_32.png')"
 onmouseover="this.style.backgroundImage = 'url( \'https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo3w.png\')'"

 onmouseout="this.style.backgroundImage = 'url( \'http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_32.png\')'"

> Soem Text
    </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this css:

```css
button {
    font-size: 18px;
    border: 2px solid #AD235E;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: background-size: contain; resizes background not the container.